# What's the difference between Ordinary, Class A and Class B Shares?

Tags: corporate-law, shareholders

I incorporated my company using an Online service. Not knowingly, I created class A, B and Ordinary shares during the incroporation. However, in the company constitution there are no mention of what differentiate these shares.

Is there a common legal definition for class A, B and Ord shares?

I live in Australia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class A and Class B are categories of common stock (also known as ordinary shares). Common stock/ordinary shares are what most investors purchase when they’re investing in the stock market.

The only difference between Class A and Class B is the voting power one receives along with the share. A company that issues multiple levels of stock usually does so to concentrate voting power. Thus, directors, for example, would own Class A shares while Class B shares are sold to the general market.

Sources:

[Class A Shares vs. Class B Shares](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/062215/what-difference-between-class-shares-and-other-common-shares-companys-stock.asp)

[What Are Ordinary Shares?](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/ordinaryshares.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just found out that in Australia, class A and class B stock definition are not defined by law. Its up to the company to define it in their constitution